# Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.how to solve this

Tags: node.js, reactjs

In my react redux app error like this (**Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.**) is showing every thing which is important to run this app are successfully installed so do not need to worry about that it google it several time but nothing happen anybody have an idea to solve this your effort will be appreciated in this case and thanks in advance

this is my action index.js

```
export function CounterActions(){
    return {
        type: "Add"
    }
}
```

this is my reducer counterApp.js

```
    const initialState = {
        counter: 0
    }

    function counterApp(state, action) {
        if (typeof state === "undefined"){
            return initialState;
        }

        switch (action.type) {
            case "Add":
                return Object.assign( {}, state, { counter: state.counter + 1 } );
            default:
                return state;
        }
    }

export default counterApp;
```

this is my store store.js

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';

import counterApp from './reducers/counterApp';

let store  = createStore(counterApp);

export default store;
```

and this is my component app.jsx

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import { CounterActions } from '../actions/index';

    class App extends Component{
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
        }
        click(){
            this.props.testClick();
        }

        render(){
            return(
                <div>
                    <h1>React Redux</h1>
                    <h2>Counter: {this.props.counter}</h2>
                    <button onClick={this.click.bind(this)}>Count ++ </button>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
        return {
            testClick: () => dispatch(CounterActions("Add"))
        }
    }

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
        return state;
    }

export default connect(mapDispatchToProps, mapStateToProps)(App);
```

Answer (score 1):

The order in which you pass arguments to `connect` is incorrect. Reverse the order of arguments and it should be fine.

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

The syntax of connect is as follows:

```
connect([mapStateToProps], [mapDispatchToProps], [mergeProps], [options])
```

Comment: i do this ( export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);) and it works fine thank a lot may you always be lucky. you have saved my time thanks once again.

Comment: Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
export function CounterActions(){
    return ({
      type: "Add"
    })
}
```

You need to put the return object in the parentheses. If you don't, then you'll definitely get this error.

[image]

Hopefully that helps!